# Momentjs date format handling (CEST) after GMT

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I've read the documentation and I just wanted to make sure if the date that I'm getting as a result properly handles the "GMT+0200 (CEST)" after the time. This is my code with the ouput:

```js
var date= moment("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss 1").format()

console.log(date)
//output:
//2017-03-27T18:44:35+02:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using `1` at the end of your format? I suggest to use `Z` instead. See [parsing doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Due to this line that is in your link : "1 GMT : +0000"

Comment: You don't need a format string for [RFC 2822 dates](https://momentjs.com/docs/#the-rfc-2822-date-time-format). Just leave it off.

Comment: Both answers work and so does mine...xD

Comment: @Tomalak the input is **not** in RFC 2822 beacuse day of month is after month name, `moment("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)")` will give _Deprecation Warning_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your format string does not handle offset properly.

The [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parsing function (note that there is only one parameter)  accepts ISO 8601 and RFC 2822 strings. This function does not use format parameter, so there is no need to use `1` anywhere. Anyway your input is not compliant to RFC 2822 because day of month is after month name. If you use `moment(String)` you will get a *Deprecation Waring* in the console, as shown in the following code:

```js
var date= moment("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)").format();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The result of previous code is inconsitent across browers, as the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) states:

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

---

As I suggested earlier in the comments, you can use moment [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing function using the `ZZ` token (*Offset from UTC as `+-HH:mm`, `+-HHmm`, or `Z`*) in order to consider UTC offset.

In your case you can combine [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) (the `ZZ`/`Z` token) with the [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) function to parse you input correctly:

```js
var date= moment.utc("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ");
// Local date, but considering input offset
console.log(date.local().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that my solution differs from your beacuse it takes in account offset string, you can use [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) method to test it as shown here (change enviroment offset if you are `UTC+2`):

```js
var myDate = moment.utc("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ");
console.log(myDate.unix()); // 1490633075

var yourDate= moment("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss 1");
console.log(yourDate.unix()); // output depends on browser offset

var targetDate = moment.utc("2017-03-27 16:44:35");
console.log(targetDate.unix()); // 1490633075
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

As a further reference you can take a look at the [**Time Zone vs Offset**](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/timezone-offset/) guide that states:

> The Moment.js core library provides functionality related to adjusting times based on an offset value. It does not provide support for adjusting dates based on time zone data - this is provided by the Moment TimeZone library.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question: no, your format string does not properly handle the timezone string.  If I run your sample code in my timezone (GMT+0100), the result I get is: `2017-03-27T18:44:35+01:00` - i.e. it looks like moment is ignoring the time-zone completely, and just using the local time-zone.

Proof:

```js
var date= moment("Mon Mar 27 2017 18:44:35 GMT-0700 (MST)", "ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss it doesn't matter what I write here").format()

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I agree with you, the OP code does not properly handle the timezone string, but this is not the only way to handle this kind of input with momentjs. You can handle offset using `Z` token, I've tried to provide a detailed answer showing it.

Comment: It'd be much better if moment issues a console warning when it ignores/doesn't understand format tokens like `Z`.  I didn't realise the significance of calling `.utc(...)` in `moment(input, format)` vs `moment.utc(input, format)`, but ... yeah, your answer has good info!